# Angular change detection to update partial page only

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I am working on an angular 5.2 app.
I have 10 tabs in my base-component. and each tab has it's own component ( 4 component). So my each tab has a very heavy processing.
Now, my question is, 
If I update any of the Tab's child component than, angular run the changeDetection on all the tabs and their child component which make my app very slow.

Is there a way to tell the angular to run change-Detection on a specific part of the   page?  I know it sounds a bit odd but I need to improve the application performance and the real issue, I see is, that Change-Detection is being run for the whole page ( 10 tabs and each tabs with 4 component).

I am not posting any code as of now as this question is a generic one but if any one thinks that code would be helpful, i can do that as well.

Comment: Don't load those components then. Comment their code.

Comment: what have you tried until now in order to improve perf.? Code would be nice to have

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

```
import {..., ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class CounterComponent {
  @Input() data;
}
```

Manually mark for change detection.

```
import {..., ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

export class CounterComponent {
    constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
  ...
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.subscribe((value) => {
      this._data = value;
      // tell CD to verify this subtree
      this.cd.markForCheck();
    });
  }
}
```

Refer doc for info : https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Comment: I am using OnPush strategy  on my child component of each Tab.  but the problem happens when I need to reload/Update whole Tab. as each Tab does not get it's data from it's parent by @Input property.  calling  ChangeDetectorRef  explicitely will run the ChangeDetection cycle for the whole page ( for all tabs and hence for all tab's child component).

Comment: It looks like a flaw in my design. Not sure but will take a look again and will post my finding. Event I was going through some articles and found that the only way to control ChangeDetection is by  the ChangeDetection Strategies which depends on the @Input and ngOnChanges.

Comment: Angular tracks binding inputs by object reference. It means that if an object reference hasn’t changed the binding change is not detected and change detection is not executed for a component that uses OnPush strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ngDoCheck lifecycle hook to check for object mutation and notify Angular using markForCheck method.

---

```
export class AComponent {
  @Input() o;  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnChanges() {
    // every time the object changes 
    // store the new `id`
    this.id = this.o.id;
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    // check for object mutation
    if (this.id !== this.o.id) {
      this.cd.markForCheck();
    }
  }
}
```